# AWS S3 Bucket copy function

Tags: amazon-s3, push, aws-cli, cp

We are trying to push +1.5 Million files via AWS CLI to a Bucket. We tried it on staging first and the task is still running (we iterate through folders). This is ongoing for 5 days now...

Is there a faster way to push that many file from a online server to the S3 bucket?

FYI: All the files are in special folders hashed in subfolders, depending on the name.

Comment: Are the files compressible?

Comment: The files are JPG and PNGs

Answer (score 2):

Below things you can try:

1. Enable S3 Transfer Acceleration [Detail](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/transfer-files-into-amazon-s3-up-to-300-percent-faster/)
2. you can use AWS Import/Export
3. use AWS DirectConnect, which establishes a dedicated private network connection (1Gbps or 10Gbps ports) between AWS and your premises. You can also make use of APN network[2] if you do not have preexisting infra at Direct Connect locations.

Answer (score 0):

First get the list of the all files and divide it in some approach, like file name starts with 1,2, .. 9. and you can start separate process of AWS CLI to upload each list. you might hit two limits one is your system limit and another s3 throttling which is roughly around 300 writes per second which is very high, so if you have very good config, you can start more number of AWS CLI to make it faster and if the files are big in size, make sure multipart upload is enabled.